# Как программно поменять цвет заголовка в alertdialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

Как можно поменять цвет заголовка в alertdialog программно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два варианта, использовать свой textView:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Select an option");
textView.setPadding(20, 30, 20, 30);
textView.setTextSize(20F);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

final CharSequence[] items = {"Visiting Card", "Prescription Letter"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setCustomTitle(textView);
builder.setItems(items, (dialog, item) -> {
    }).show();
```

либо сделать стиль:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">your color here</item>
</style>
```

и:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme)
        .setTitle("Hello world")
        .setMessage("some longer text for the body of the dialog")
        .show();
```

либо через тег `setTitleColor()` и дальше уже при нажатии на кнопку или как вы там его менять планируете менять, изменять его.

Answer (score 1):

```
Вы можете придать стиль своему Alertdialog следующим образом:

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
```

И стиль выглядит вот так:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f3f3f3</item>
</style>
```